# Unmounting encfs volumes from the nautilus side tab does not work

Tags: nautilus, unmount

It is only an annoyance, but I would like to get rid of it: I can easily `mount` gvfs- end encfs-volumes from the nautilus side tab. I can unmount at least the gvfs-volumes easily by clicking the "eject"-icon, which appears in the nautilus side tab as soon as the gvfs-volume is mounted. But I can't unmount mounted encfs-volumes the same way. trying this I always get an error message telling me, that unmount couldn't find the directory to be unmounted in fstab. This parallels to the commandline behaviour, where I can do `umount /path/to/gvfsdir` but not `umount /path/to/encfsdir`. To unmount encfsdir I have to type: `fusermount -u /path/to/encfsdir`. Following is the encfs-volume-entry in `/etc/fstab`.

`/path/to/encfs-script#/path/to/crypted/volume /path/to/encfsdir fuse rw, nosuid,nedev,default_permissions,noauto,user 0 0`

Is there any option I missed to allow `/path/to/encfs` to be unmounted using the 'eject'-button in the nautilus side tab?